# How to create a button which opens a given spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a new button in the UI to open a new spreadsheet when clicking on it. I seems really simple but I have been looking around and I can't find what I'm looking for.

So far, I know how to create my button on the UI but I can't add the function behind to open the spreadsheet.

```
function onOpen() {

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Button') // my button name
      .addToUi();
 }
```

Do you know how I could achieve this?

Comment: That's not a "button", it's a menu - the text in this question may confuse people.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I missed the important part. Let me try again. This approach does not open a new spreadsheet from a button. It creates a new spreadsheet then creates a hyperlink to the new spreadsheet (in this example in "A1"). I do not think a new spreadsheet can be created and opened directly from a button. Give this a try. Each time the button a new spreadsheet and new hyperlink is created.

```
 function onOpen() {
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu(
    'Create Spreadsheet', [ 
      { name: 'New Spreadsheet', functionName: 'newSprdsht' }, 
      ]);   
 }
function newSprdsht(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create("New Spreadsheet "+new Date());//create a new  spreadsheet with new name each run
var url = ss.getUrl();//get url of new spreadsheet
var s=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var s1=s.getActiveSheet()
var cell =s1.getRange("A1")// where to put the hyperlink
var v='=HYPERLINK(\"'+url+'\",\"New Spreadsheet\")'
cell.setFormula(v)
}
```

Comment: Dear Ed, thx for answering. Do you know how I can script the function to properly open the spreadsheet?

Comment: Go to the 'Tools' menu on any sheet and select the'Script Editor'. In the script editor, delete all of the myFunction code. Then copy and paste the above code in the script editor. Run the code in the script editor. You will get two popups asking for permission . Accept. After that the menu code will run each time the spreadsheet is opened. Change the code to meet your needs. If you have any problems, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can't open a sheet directly from the menu but it can open a pop-up that will have a link to open the sheet.

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Google Sheet").addItem("Open", "openSheet_").addToUi();
}

function openSheet_() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var url = ss.getUrl(); // replace this with another URL
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<a href='URL' target='_blank'>Open Sheet</a>".replace("URL", url));
  ss.show(html.setHeight(100).setWidth(200));
}
```